# How to meet dependencies for Python3.4 in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, python, dependencies

I upgraded  my system from 14.04 to 16.04,

Ubuntu 16.04 has Python 3.5, but I also installed Py 3.4.

But nothing actually works.

like I pip3.4 installed Django, there were many unmet dependencies like no module named social, I installed that then there were errors like no module named PyLib, scipy etc.

Now I am running a selenium code and this is the error:

```
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''
```

what should I do for this now?

Comment: Update your question with more details,like what as the unmet dependencies etc? By the way,why installing old python3 release??

Comment: How did you install Python 3.4 and pip?

Comment: @edwinksl I installed with sudo apt-get install python3.4..and don't remember exactly for pip.  arduino I thought 3.5 may have dependency issues for my existing projects.